# @Context not injecting ServletContext in RESTEasy JAX-RS application

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy, jboss6.x

I am deploying a JAX-RS application to JBoss EAP 6.2.
I am trying to obtain a `ServletContext` from inside of a JAX-RS resource class so that I can read some `context-param` values that I have set in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.
I.e., after I've gotten hold of the `ServletContext` I was planning to call `ServletContext#getInitParam` to get the value.
I am using injection to get the `ServletContext` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814788/274677).

The relevant portion of my `web.xml` is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>foo.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jax-rs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So I am using RESTEasy which is bundled with JBoss.

Class `MyApplication` is:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public MyApplication() {
        singletons.add( new MyResource() );
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

… and finally in class `MyResource` I have the following:

```
@Path(...)
public class MyResource {

    @Context
    ServletContext context;

    public MyResource() {
        // I understand context is supposed to be null here
    }

    // ... but it should have been injected by the time we reach the service method.
    @Path("/somePath")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public Response someMethod( ) {
        if (context==null) throw new RuntimeException();
        ...
    }
}
```

The above code always results in the `RuntimeException` being thrown. I.e. RESTEasy somehow fails to inject the `ServletContext`. Note that I don't have any other JAX-RS problems. I.e. if I hardcode the `context-param` values I was hoping to be able to retrieve via `ServletContext#getInitParameter", then the JAX-RS rest functionality works as expected when the WAR is deployed to JBoss.

Experimenting further I discovered that the `ServletContext`is only injected if I perform the injection at an argument of the service method like this:

```
@Path("/somePath")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response someMethod(@Context ServletContext servletContext) {
    ...
}
```

… however I would prefer not to change the API. Moreover, I would like to perform some costly initialization based on the `context-param` value once and for all, not on every service method invocation.

My questions are:

1. why is the injection failing?
2. I am a little tired of the annotations magic failing at runtime, is there a way to get the `ServletContext` without using annotations?
3. Alternatively, is it possible for my `MyApplication` class to obtain the `ServletContext` and pass it to the `MyResource` class as a constructor parameter?
4. If all else fails I guess I can always read and parse the web.xml file myself using `Class#getResourceAsStream` ?

Comment: Have a look  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814517/get-servletcontext-in-jax-rs-resource?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @gladiator I specifically link to that answer in my question (at the opening paragraph)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434667/rest-easy-and-init-params-how-to-access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment by FrAn that links to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540203/274677), this is what I ended up doing:

```
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public JaxRsApplication(@Context ServletContext servletContext) {
        Assert.assertNotNull(servletContext);
        singletons.add( new UserDatabaseResource(servletContext) );
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

… and then, in the `UserDatabaseResource` class I have the following:

```
public UserDatabaseResource(ServletContext servletContext) {
    Assert.assertNotNull(servletContext);
    ...
    String jndiNameForDatasource = servletContext.getInitParameter("whatever")) ;
    ...
}
```

This works as the `UserDatabaseResource` class which is my DAL layer is a singleton and I just needed to get the JNDI name of the datasource to use (from the `web.xml` file). But maybe this approach also works with some minor adjustments for non-singleton classes as well.